# My own "Cookie Clicker" Game

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, game, ecmascript-6

I tried to make my own Cookie Clicker Game. It's inspired from [this game](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/).

Here I just wanted to practice object-oriented programming in JavaScript (and in general) and get experience in game design. If you have tips for a better design or for a better performance, please let me know!

**Short Game Description**

You have to produce cookies. You can improve your cookie production by improving the clicker or the buildings. The clicker generates 1 cookie + 5 % of your total production of all buildings. You can unlock new buildings if you have produced enough cookies.

```js
// classes
// functions
// commands and global variables

// classes

class Clicker
{
 constructor()
 {
  this.level = 1
  this.price = 20;

  this.level_display = document.getElementById("clicker_level");
  this.price_display = document.getElementById("clicker_price");
  this.productivity_display = document.getElementById("clicker_productivity");

  this.renew_display();
 }

 click()
 {
  cookies += this.get_production_value();
  cookies_produced += this.get_production_value();
  renew_cookies();
 }

 get_production_value()
 {
  return Math.floor(1 + (0.05 * altogether_productivity * (this.level - 1)) + (this.level - 1));
 }

 improve()
 {
  if(cookies >= this.price)
  {
   cookies -= this.price;
   this.level += 1;
   this.price *= 2;
   this.renew_display();
  }
  else
  {
   alert("Not enough cookies!");
  }
 }

 renew_display()
 {
  this.level_display.innerHTML = this.level;
  this.price_display.innerHTML = this.price;
  this.productivity_display.innerHTML = this.get_production_value();
 }
}

class Building
{
 constructor(name, productivity, price)
 {
  this.name = name;
  this.level = 0;
  this.price = price;
  this.productivity = productivity;

  // variables for displaying
  // definition of areas
  this.area = document.createElement("span");
  this.area.id = name;

  this.level_display = document.createElement("span");
  this.level_display.id = this.name + "_level";

  this.productivity_display = document.createElement("span");
  this.productivity_display.id = this.name + "_productivity";

  this.price_display = document.createElement("span");
  this.price_display.id = this.name + "_price";

  this.button = document.createElement("button");
  this.button.innerHTML = "Improve";
         this.button.onclick = this.improve.bind(this);

  // put together
  this.area.append(document.createTextNode(name + " Level: "));
  this.area.append(this.level_display);
  this.area.append(document.createElement("br"));

  this.area.append(document.createTextNode("Cookies per Second: "));
  this.area.append(this.productivity_display);
  this.area.append(document.createElement("br"));

  this.area.append(document.createTextNode("Improvement Price: "));
  this.area.append(this.price_display);
  this.area.append(document.createElement("br"));

  this.area.append(this.button);
  this.area.append(document.createElement("br"));
  this.area.append(document.createElement("br"));
        
         setInterval(this.produce.bind(this), 1000);
 }
 
 get_price() 
 {
  return (this.price / 2) * (this.level * this.level + 1) + (this.price / 2) * (this.level + 1)
 }
 
 improve()
 {
         if(cookies >= this.get_price())
         {
          cookies -= this.get_price();
          this.level += 1;
          altogether_productivity += this.productivity;
          this.renew_display();
          clicker.renew_display();
         }
         else
         {
   alert("Not enough cookies!");
  }
 }

 renew_display()
 {
  this.level_display.innerHTML = this.level;
  this.productivity_display.innerHTML = this.get_production_value();
  this.price_display.innerHTML = this.get_price();
 }


 set_visible()
 {
  buildings.append(this.area);
  this.renew_display();
 }

 produce()
 {
  cookies += this.get_production_value();
  cookies_produced += this.get_production_value();
 }
 
 get_production_value()
 {
  return this.level * this.productivity;
 }
}

// functions

function renew_cookies()
{
 cookies_display.innerHTML = cookies;
 cookies_produced_display.innerHTML = cookies_produced;
    
 if(this.cookies_produced >= 200 && bakery_enabled == 0) 
 {
  bakery.set_visible();
  bakery_enabled = 1;
        
 }
 if(this.cookies_produced >= 2000 && factory_enabled == 0)
 {
  factory.set_visible(); 
  factory_enabled = 1;
 }
 if(this.cookies_produced >= 20000 && cookie_tesla_enabled == 0)
 {
  cookie_tesla.set_visible();
  cookie_tesla_enabled = 1;
 }

 if(this.cookies_produced >= 200000 && cookie_gigant_enabled == 0) 
 {
  cookie_gigant.set_visible(); 
  cookie_gigant_enabled = 1;
 }
}

// commands and (global) variables

var cookies = 0;
var cookies_produced = 0;
var altogether_productivity = 0; // counts productivity of buildings except clicker

var cookies_display = document.getElementById("cookies");
var cookies_produced_display = document.getElementById("cookies_produced");

var buildings = document.getElementById("buildings");

bakery_enabled = 0;
factory_enabled = 0;
cookie_tesla_enabled = 0;
cookie_gigant_enabled = 0;

clicker = new Clicker();
baker = new Building("Baker", 1, 20);
baker.set_visible();
bakery = new Building("Bakery", 10, 200);
factory = new Building("Factory", 100, 2000);
cookie_tesla = new Building("Cookie Tesla", 1000, 20000);
cookie_gigant = new Building("Cookie Gigant", 10000, 200000);

setInterval(renew_cookies, 500);
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <b>Number of Cookies: <span id="cookies"></span></b><br>
  Cookies produced: <span id="cookies_produced"></span><br>
  <button onclick="clicker.click();">Make Cookie!</button><br><br>

  Clicker Level: <span id="clicker_level"></span><br>
  Production: <span id="clicker_productivity"></span><br>
  Improvement Price: <span id="clicker_price"></span><br>
  <button onclick="clicker.improve();">Improve</button><br><br>

  <hr><br>
  <span id="buildings"></span>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Object-oriented code

The OO code looks like a good start, though for a larger application, some separation of model and view logic may be necessary. Also, the constructor of the *Building* class is a bit long. I would recommend abstracting out the code to add elements into separate methods- a template might make that process simpler.

#### Properly accessing the DOM

Before accessing DOM elements, it would be wise to wait until the DOM has been loaded. [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) can be used on `document` to wait for the [*DOMContentLoaded*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var cookies_display = document.getElementById("cookies");
    var cookies_produced_display = document.getElementById("cookies_produced");

    var buildings = document.getElementById("buildings");
    //rest of code using cookies_display, cookies_produced_display and buildings
});
```

For more tips about optimizations with Javascript interacting with the DOM, I recommend [this article](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/02/stop-writing-slow-javascript/). It has some tips like:

- **Caching DOM lookups** - while there appears to be only one *Clicker* instance, each time the constructor is called it gets two elements by Id. Those should be cached in variables - and perhaps assigned once the DOMContentLoaded event is triggered.
- **Adding new elements to a document fragment** - Apparently the code in the *Building* constructor does something similar to this with the `<span>` element assigned to the *area* property.